# Prog em C informando se x é divisível

Tags: portugol

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo certo?

Estou dando continuidade aos meus exercícios em C, e fiquei preso em mais um.
Aqui vai o enunciado do mesmo:

***Escreva um algoritmo que receba um número do teclado e informar se ele é divisível por 8, por 5, por 2 ou se não é divisível por nenhum destes. Verifique para cada um dos números.
Exemplo:
Número: 8
Divisível por 8
Divisível por 2***

Meu código:

```
inicio

      escreva("Digite um número: ")
      leia(num)

      d2 <- (num%2)
      d5 <- (num%5)
      d8 <- (num%8)

      soma <- d2+d5+d8

      se (soma = 0) entao
         escreval("Número não é divisível por nenhuma das opções (2, 4 e 5)")
      senao
           se (d2 = 0) entao
              escreval("Número divisível por 2")
           senao
                se (d5 = 0) entao
                   escreval("Número divisível por 5")
                senao
                     se (d8 = 0) entao
                        escreval("Número divisível por 8")
                     fimse
                fimse
           fimse
      fimse

fimalgoritmo
```

Só que, ele só se eu digitar "8" por exemplo, ele diz que é divisível apenas por 2. E quando digito 40, ele disse que não é divisível por nenhuma das opções.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa?

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois problemas nesse algoritmo.
O primeiro problema é relativo ao primeiro `se`:

```
se (soma = 0) entao
```

Quando a soma é zero, significa que é divisível por todos e não que não é divisível por nenhum.

Já o segundo problema é relativo ao entrelaçamento dos se/senao. Por exemplo, quando você diz que:

```
se (d2 = 0) entao
    escreval("Número divisível por 2")
senao
```

Isso você está dizendo, entre nesse se, caso algo aconteça, senão faça isso. Entretanto, o `se/senao` só devem ser utilizados quando uma condição influência na outra, o que não é o caso nessa situação. o fato dele ser divisível por 2, não torna ele não divisível por 5 ou por 8, então esses `se`s não deveriam ser aninhados.

Comment: Então, em relação ao primeiro `se` eu devo usar `se (soma <> 0) entao`? E em relação ao entrelaçamento de `se/senao` eu não devo usar o `senao` e sim o `fimse` de acordo com cada abertura da repetição?

Comment: Eu fiz as alterações, e realmente agora ele está contando certinho por quais que o num é divisível, certinho. Porém, ele está imprimindo o `se (soma<>0) entao` em todos os casos.

Comment: Retornei o primeiro `se` para o que estava primeiramente: `se (soma=0) entao` e ele está rodando corretamente. O único porém é o número 80, que está imprimido TODAS as mensagens dos `se`.

Comment: @tspereirarj ele roda todas as mensagens do `se, porque todos dividem o número, tem várias formas de resolver, a ideal seria ir "juntando" a string conforme fosse tendo as divisões. Por exemplo, entrou no senão (é divisível por algum número), faz o seguinte: `res <- "esse número é divisível por: "` e ir concantenando por quem é divisível nessa variável res e dar um `escreval` nela no final.